# ¿Cómo crear un json field en un modelo de django?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

`import json
campos = JSONField(null = True, blank = True)`

tengo esto y me genera el siguiente error:
**NameError: name 'JSONField' is not defined**

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer `JSONField` es un tipo exclusivo de PostgreSQL, según lo que leí en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField).

Si tu estás usando PostgreSQL, entonces deberías importar desde ese módulo, no desde el `json` nativo de Python.

Deberías hacer la siguiente importación:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```

Yo por mi parte, te recomiendo preprocesar los json y guardarlos como `TextField` y al consultarlos realizar el proceso de conversión a la inversa.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este es el paquete que necesitas: [jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield).

Lo he utilizado en varios proyectos con MySQL y me ha venido de maravilla.